# Vertical align elements evenly in autolayout

Tags: interface-builder, uiswitch, ios9

In Interface Builder, I have five `UISwitch` elements. I want to lay to have the same spacing between the elements, when I lay them out horizontally.

[image: Current state of UISwitches]

How do I set the autolayout so that they'll be evenly spaced, but without filler views?
I've tried setting the left and right margin constraints, but that resulted in conflicts about the horizontal hugging. As you can see in the Simulator screenshot, that is my current situation with the equal margins **after** AutoLayout asked me to act on the horizontal hugging.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the new iOS9 class [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/)